# Is an .exe, built from C, vulnerable to reverse engineering?

Tags: c, security, exe, reverse-engineering

I wanted to export my C code and demonstrate its abilities.
I saw in many references that an `.exe` file can be restored using reverse engineering.

Is there a way of demonstrating my code while being sure (of course, it's never 100% safe) it won't be restored and copied?

Comment: Depends on what do you mean by "restored". The original source code/design is reasonably "protected" if the application is complex enough and optimizations were enabled; but you cannot truly protect the data or alterations to its behavior (there are ways to make this more complex, though).

Comment: Im just third-year student that came with an idea and afraid someone will take it before I could publish. What's so strange with that?

Comment: @Acorn how?
And it's not supposed to be so complex.

Comment: When we were in our third year we had to decompile programs.

Comment: @Zooly92: The simpler the application is, the easier to find out what it is doing -- even with optimizations enabled. It depends on what your idea is about. If, for instance, you are trying to protect a revolutionary algorithm, then you should look into obfuscating it. If you are trying to protect just the source code, then compiling it with optimizations may be enough.

Comment: First of all I would suggest a bit of modesty. Do you really think that people  will spend  hours  reverse engineering  your code? I saw in my programming life a lots of a "revolutionary" students ideas, which were not as revolutionary as the authors  were thinking. My advice - two words : modesty and trust.

Comment: @wildplasser well I'm not studying computer science.

Comment: It is exactly about it. BTW to be 100% sure never ever release any executables.  Keep them in the safe  Do not even display or edit the sours codes as your screen or keyboard may be captured.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 It is not about modesty. 
I wouldn't have asked this without a good reason.
And saying that it takes hours to restore it also helps. You assumed I knew that, and I didn't:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean:

1. If you want to protect an **algorithm** (i.e. a novel idea implemented in software), then the only real way to protect it is to never share the actual file. In other words, demonstrate it only on hardware you control.
2. If you want to protect the **source code** or original **design**, then typically compiling with optimizations enabled is good enough for most cases. Potential competitors will be able to just code it from scratch if needed -- there is not much gain for them by reverse engineering it.
3. If you want to protect its run-time **behavior** (e.g. disabling a license check) or its **data** (e.g. assets), see the first point -- the same applies.

Obfuscation can help you buy *some* time, though. However, for the first and third cases, only very complex schemes will actually delay reverse engineering attempts.

Comment: I meant protecting the source code.,
I'll look how to use compiling with optimizations. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to recover the original source code from the compiled executable; just as it is not possible to create an egg from an omelette.

It is of course possible to disassemble the generated machine code, and from that with significant effort reverse-engineer what that code does and how it works.  It is even possible using specialist tools to "decompile" and generate a high-level language or pseudo-code representation of the executable - but it will bare little resemblance to the original code, and will contain none of the original symbol names of comments.

Any moderately complex software will be very difficult and time-consuming to usefully reverse engineer, and you have to balance that risk with the value of code, and the likelihood that reverse-engineering has any value to a third-party. Unless you have some particularly valuable and novel IP, in most cases it is easier to simply observe the external function of the code as a black-box and reproduce the functionality rather than attempting steal the IP.

If all you are concerned about is that your fellow students will copy your homework - that cannot happen, not in any way that they could submit before a deadline. It would be easier for them to do the work themselves.  If they are incapable of doing that; they are probably incapable of reverse-engineering it - because that is probably harder.